# Morphological Difference

Tags: morphology

I'm challenging with this question:

> Which word is morphologically different from others?
>
> 1. fishy
> 2. dirty
> 3. pinky (answer)
> 4. sneaky

Could anyone, kindly, give me some instruction on why choice 3 is correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If "pinky" means "the smallest finger or toe", it's really morphologically different, since it's not constructed of two morphemes, root + -y, "pinky" is [a borrowing from Dutch](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pinky#Etymology_2) *pinkje*, diminutive of Dutch *pink* (“little finger”). Note that there's also an alternative spelling of the word, "pinkie".

That question is tricky and allows different answers, for example "pinky" can be considered as meaning "pinkish" and in this case it's constructed of two morphemes, just the same way as the rest of the words in the question, "pink + -y". And yes, the question presupposes the knowledge of the etymology of all those word, or at least access to an etymological dictionary.

Comment: It is therefore bi-morphemic in Dutch, but not in English (in that meaning).

Comment: The question doesn't presuppose etymological knowledge -- the other three words are transparently derived synchronically from an existing word plus *-y*, while *pinky* (in its normal meaning) is not.

Comment: @TKR It is sneaky (!) in that, given this list of four words, the natural reading of _pinky_ is ‘pinkish’, rather than ‘little finger’. 4 would be an equally correct answer (it’s formed by adding _-y_ to a verb stem, whereas the others are formed by adding it to a noun stem).

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Hi! In that case, 'fish' can be considered as a verb, too. We are obliged to act through the method mentioned by Yellow Sky, to have just one correct answer. Of course, despite the high formality of the source of this test, It sounds kind of non-standard; which means you have pointed out a worth-to-mention point. THANKSSSSSSS....

Comment: @elyarabad It’s true that _fish_ can also be a verb, but _fishy_ is derived from the noun, not the verb; _sneak_, on the other hand, is derived from the verb, not the (much rarer) noun meaning ‘someone who sneaks or cheats’.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I've never heard *pinky* used to mean "pinkish". Apparently it exists, but I doubt it's a meaning that would readily occur to most native speakers. (Though if that is the intended meaning, it would be an adjective stem, not a verb stem.)

Comment: @TKR It’s a normal enough word to me – I’ve used it, though admittedly I’d probably be more likely to use _pinkish_. For some reason, _pinky_ feels like its base is the noun _pink_ rather than the adjective, but I’m not sure why. Perhaps it’s just that _-y_ generally favours nouns (I can’t think of a single unambiguously adjectival stem off the top of my head except perhaps _goody_, but then that isn’t really used as a regular _-y_ adjective).

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I think that preference is precisely why *pinky* "pinkish" sounds wrong to me. Out of curiosity, do you also have *greeny, reddy* etc.? To me the only such word that's borderline acceptable is *yellowy* (for some reason), and I'm not sure about that one.

Comment: @TKR Yup, most of the colour-based ones work fine for me. _Whity_ perhaps not so much, due to blocking from nominal _whitey_, and I doubt I’d ever use _blacky_, but the others are all fine. _Orangey_ I even find preferable to _orange-ish_, for some reason. Perhaps something to do with syllables and stress. Actually, all the disyllabic bases – _yellowy_, _orangey_, _purply_, etc. – seem equally or even more natural/preferable to me than their _-ish_ counterparts.